# bottleneck node taking long time to return

Tags: neo4j

we're on neo4j 2.1.4 soon to upgrade to 2.2.1.

We've been experiencing some slow downs with certain cypher queries and I think they are mostly centered around two to three nodes out of millions in the graph. These nodes were created with the intent on having some monitoring put in place to check the availability of the graph. I've since found out that a few apps that have been built are actually exercising these queries before actually performing their write operations on the graph. Then I found out that our load balancer was setup to actually do some tests through multiple apps that end up querying the same nodes. So we have a large mix of applications that are all either pulling or updating these same nodes. This has resulted in those two nodes taking anywhere from 8 to 40 seconds to be returned.

Is there any way to determine how many updates and how many queries are being issued against one node?

Answer (score 1):

Since Neo4j 2.2 there's a config option to log queries taking longer than a given threshold, see the `dbms.querylog.XXXX` settings in http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-settings.html.

To get an update count for a given node you could setup a custom `TransactionEventHandler` that tracks write accesses to your given nodes.

Comment: So there isn't any way out of the box to do this?  I really need to track down every thing hitting these nodes. 

Is there any circumstance where reads against a single node would block each other or slow the results down to >45 sec response times?